# Proving that some truncations have the same expected value (using Lebesgue integral)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $X_1,X_2\colon(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)\to (\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ be two random real variables, where $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ denotes a probability space. And $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ denotes the real number and the borel sets.

If $X_1, X_2$ have the same distribution, i.e for any $B\in\mathcal  B(\mathbb R)$ we have:

$\mathbb P(X_1\in B)=\mathbb P(X_2 \in B)$.

Prove that $\mathbb EX_11_{|X_1|\le n}=\mathbb EX_21_{|X_2|\le n}$.

Here $\mathbb EX=\int_{\Omega} X \mathrm d\mathbb P$ denotes the Lebesgue integral with respect to the measure P and $1_A$ denotes the characteristic function of the set $A$.

Please I need to prove this to prove a result about a weak law of large numbers.

Comment: "a set endowed with a σ-algebra F, and a probability P" is called a *probability space*. // "Here EX=∫ΩXdP denotes the Lebesgue integral" No it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some useful facts:

1. If $U$ and $V$ are integrable random variables with the same distribution, they have the same expectation.
2. If $U$ and $V$ have the same distribution and $\phi\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is Borel-measurable, then $\phi(U)$ and $\phi(V)$ have the same distribution.
3. The map $\phi(x):=x\chi_{\{|x|\leqslant n\}}$ is Borel-measurable.

Comment: note that here we are considering different characteristic functions on each different set

Comment: I'm not sure if they have the same distribution. I'm can't prove it. Well I only need to prove that they same the same expected value. Please help me )=

Comment: Compute $\mathbb P\{X\chi_{|X|\leqslant n}\leqslant t\}$ for a fixed $t$.

Comment: I tried, but I can't D:

Comment: Discuss the case $t\leqslant n$ and $t\gt n$.

Comment: the difficult case it's when $t\le n$